# Change Debug Mode via URL in one and the same environment in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am using Larvel 4 and have set up diferent environments. Onw for my local developement and one for the live server. But sometimes something works in my dev env. but not on the live server. So I wish I would be able to enable Debug mode on the live server without having to change the config file.

I imagine something like adding ?dev=true to the URL.

Is there something built-in or would I have to develope it on my own?

Thanks!

Comment: It is dangerous to enable debug mode via a URL parameter because anyone could turn it on or off at any time, potentially gaining access to sensitive information.

Comment: Consider creating an environment that mirrors production exactly to reproduce the error, or temporarily edit the config file to enable debug mode on the live site after blocking public access.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the log file to view any errors: `app/storage/logs/laravel.log`.

There, you can find the same info as you would on the "Whoops" screen--albeit much in a less elegant presentation.

For a long-term solution, I'd encourage setting up a staging environment as George suggested.